# Navigation controller array has same viewcontroller multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uinavigationcontroller, ios9

In my project, when i navigated to different viewcontrollers several times my navigationController array has the following values:

```
 NSLog(@"navigationControllerArray>>>%@",[self.navigationController viewControllers]);
```

Output:

```
    "<LoginViewController: 0x7fa2a9c23910>",
    "<CategoryListViewController: 0x7fa2a9f5abd0>",
    "<SearchNewViewController: 0x7fa2aa82e600>",
    "<FavoriteViewController: 0x7fa2a9cc3ef0>",
    "<EditProfileViewController: 0x7fa2ab0c2c00>",
    "<FavoriteViewController: 0x7fa2ac3102a0>",
    "<EditProfileViewController: 0x7fa2aa0c1000>",
    "<FavoriteViewController: 0x7fa2ac184210>",
    "<EditProfileViewController: 0x7fa2aa8efa00>",
    "<SearchNewViewController: 0x7fa2aa8ab400>"
```

here you can see same viewcontrollers like *searchNewViewcontroller*,*FavoutiteViewController* and *EditProfileViewcontroller* appearing multiple times in nvaigation controller array, and i want to ask, will it make any trouble in memory management , or anything wrong with this type of navigation, if so what is the correct way of navigation. 
Hope your help. Thanks.

Comment: Well it's not normally a good thing to have multiple instances of an object that you don't plan to use, or zombie objects that have dead references but haven't been deallocated. These kind of things tend to cause memory leaks. Whether or not it will have a noticeable effect on your app's performance is hard to say. If you navigate away enough times to the point where there are hundreds of dead UIViewControllers just sitting in the background of your app, it could bog your app down, but there's no way to really say exactly how much memory each View Controller is using.

Comment: My advice would be to, first and foremost, try to figure out why this is happening in the first place, but also to run a profiler on your app and see what happens to your memory and CPU usage as the number of instances grows. If you want more help, you're going to have to post some code, as otherwise it is really hard to tell you what exactly is going wrong here.

Comment: @David: its happening because iam navigating to the same viewcontroller multiple time, but how can i restrict to occupy those viewcontrollers only once in navigation controller array...?